# How to convert float to timedelta seconds in python?

Tags: python, excel, floating-point, timedelta

How do you instantiate a `datetime.timedelta` to a number of seconds in python? For example, 43880.6543

**Edit (as per clarification by OP)**: I have an Excel sheet, where a cell shows 43880.6543 (when the format is Generic) instead of a date. How do I convert this value to a `datetime` in python?

Comment: At least give us some code to show us what exactly you want to know?

Comment: You can use directly import `timedelta` from `datetime` and `print timedelta(43880.6543)` will print `43880 days, 15:42:11.520000` ? Or you want something else ?!

Comment: Or timedelta(seconds=43880.6543)

Comment: Hm. Downvoted 5 times at least yet the question is clear...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use

```
from datetime import timedelta

value = timedelta(seconds=43880.6543)
```

You can check the value is ok with

```
value.total_seconds()
```

**Edit**: If, in an Excel spreadsheet, you have a date expressed as a number, you can use python to convert that number into a `datetime` by doing this:

```
value = datetime(1900, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=43880.6543)
# value will be February 2nd, 2020 in the afternoon
```

Comment: Sir, `43880.6543` is actually an excel date, it is represented this way when you change cell's format to `General`. Could you plewase revise your answer?